# preg_split ignore inside brackets

Tags: php, regex

`id,firstname,addresses{id,city},foo`

I want to split it by `,` but not inside curly brackets, so that the output is

```
id
firstname
addresses{id,city}
foo
```

And I'm really struggling with negative and look ahead params. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


$re = '/(?:[^,{]|\{[^}]*\})+/';
$str = 'id,firstname,addresses{id,city},foo';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

[Details for the regex](https://regex101.com/r/072Ft0/1/):

```
/ (?:[^,{]|\{[^}]*\})+ / g

Non-capturing group (?:[^,{]|\{[^}]*\})+
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as any times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

    1st Alternative [^,{]

        Match a single character not present in the list below [^,{]
        ,{ matches a single character in the list ,{ (case sensitive)

    2nd Alternative \{[^}]*\}
    \{ matches the character { literally (case sensitive)

        Match a single character not present in the list below [^}]
        * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
        } matches the character } literally (case sensitive)
    \} matches the character } literally (case sensitive)

Global pattern flags
    g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```

Result looks like: [Online PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa1569dd4a3e2b3d1faded94d7ed2ce58e001a4b)

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "id"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "firstname"
    [2]=>
    string(18) "addresses{id,city}"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "foo"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{[^{}]*}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/GMPFX6/1).

**EXPLANATION**:

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  {                        '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^{}]*                   any character except: '{', '}' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }                        '}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (*SKIP)(*FAIL)           skip & go on searching for the next match
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                         or
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ,                          a comma
```

**[PHP code](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4BLpShVwVZBXb86Oq66NlarVkMr2NszQFNDy83R00ezRkc/V92aS6W4pAikKjNFJy2zqLgkLzE3VScxJaUotbg4tbgaKJycWVJZq5OWnw9UXVCUmVcSX6RRUJSaHl9ckJNZogG0RUcBZIqmpvX//wA)**:

```php
<?php
$re = '/{[^{}]*}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,/';
$str = 'id,firstname,addresses{id,city},foo';
print_r(preg_split($re, $str));
```

**Results**:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => firstname
    [2] => addresses{id,city}
    [3] => foo
)
```